# How to store image from collectionviewcell to core data

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I have an entity called `Task` where `taskImage` is an attribute of binary data. I have the following

```
 @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
 var imageSelected = [UIImage]()
```

Then I have collection view as follows

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.imageSelected.count

    }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
                as! EditCollectionViewCell

            cell.imageView?.image =  imageSelected[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 3

              return cell
        }
```

Now I am trying to save image to core data when Save bar button item is pressed as follows

```
 @IBAction func saveBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let context =   (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        let task = Task(context: context)

        task.taskDesc = taskText.text!
 //task.taskImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(cell.imageView?.image)

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

I am getting error for taskImage, any help regarding storing image will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you detail the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code to store image in core data

```
let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

let newContact = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Contact", inManagedObjectContext: context)
let imageData:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgViewPhoto.image!, 1)!
newContact.setValue(imageData, forKey: "imageData")
```

and retrieve it from coredata

```
let imageData:NSData = contact.valueForKey("imageData") as! NSData
imgViewPhoto.image = UIImage(data: imageData, scale: 1)
```

Comment: I believe your imgViewPhoto is of type UIImageview. But my image is a part of collection view, so the above will not work for me

Comment: So when you press save button, which image will be saved?

Comment: I want to save the selected image from array of images I have in collection view

Comment: But the **imageSelected** is an array of images. Do you want to save only 1 or all iamges in array?

Comment: I want to save only 1 image

Comment: How do you know which image is the selected image in an array of images?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124620/discussion-between-coder221-and-dinh-quang-hiu).